# Assign keyboard shortcut to run procedure

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press F5 in the VBA editor I would always like to run my "Sub Skynet()" procedure. Is there any way to assign a keyboard shortcut to this procedure.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For assigning a keyboard key to button on the sheet you can use this code, just copy this code to the sheet which contain the button.

Here `Return` specifies the key and `get_detail` is the procedure name.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.OnKey "{RETURN}", "get_detail"

End Sub
```

Now within this sheet whenever you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> button the assigned macro will be called.

Comment: This answer provides more flexibility.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to asign this code to "Workbook_open" event.

Comment: A combination of `OnKey` and `Workbook_Open` let me create a combination which works on every machine.

Comment: The documentation for this can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461.aspx

Comment: something that got me with this, if you use Application.OnKey "^R" instead of "^r" you will have to use the shift key when you go to use the shortcut that you think it CTRL+R

Comment: Is there a way to specify the module name in the second string? I sometimes have macros of the same name but different modules and I want to distinguish them for different shortcut keys.

Answer (score 39):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/run-a-macro-HP005202306.aspx)

1. On the Tools menu, point to Macro, and then click Macros.
2. In the Macro name box, enter the name of the macro you want to assign to a keyboard shortcut key.
3. Click Options.
4. If you want to run the macro by pressing a keyboard shortcut key, enter a letter in the Shortcut key box. You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ letter (for lowercase letters) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ letter (for uppercase letters), where letter is any letter key on the keyboard. The shortcut key cannot use a number or special character, such as `@` or `#`.

   Note: The shortcut key will override any equivalent default Microsoft Excel shortcut keys while the workbook that contains the macro is open.
5. If you want to include a description of the macro, type it in the Description box.
6. Click OK.
7. Click Cancel.

Comment: As a sidenote @user1283776, be carefull when using `Shift` and `Application.Workbooks.Open(path)` all together, it seems that there is a known bug that make the vb script hang. See details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409524

Comment: I slightly disagre with 4. I can use CTRL + # and CTRL+(0-9) at least setting it via code. But I have some trouble with ALT+(0-9) right now.

Comment: It seems like this may not be possible from the VBE anymore. I did it through the ribbon: Developer -> Macros -> YourMacroName -> Options. That seemed to work.

Comment: DuleSilver's comment seems to be the answer in Excel 365 (at least towards the end of 2019).

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to assign a keyboard shortcut to a custom macro in Word 2013.
The scenario is you created a macro named "fred" and you want to execute the macro by typing Ctrl+f.

1. Click on File, Options.
2. Click on Customize Ribbon (from my perspective this is the non-intuitive step).
3. Click "Keyboard shortcuts: Customize" button.
4. In the Categories listbox scroll down to the buttom and select Macros.
5. The Macros list box should now show the list of custom macros.  Select "fred".
6. Click the "Press new shortcut key" textbox to make it active.
7. Type Ctrl+f.  This should appear in the textbox.
8. Look at the "Current keys" listbox.  In this case it shows "Currently assigned to NavPaneSearch".
9. If you don't mind overriding that default, click the "Assign" button on the lower-left  to assign "Ctrl+f: to run your "fred" macro.

By default the assignment is saved in the Normal.dotm document template.  If this keyboard assignment is unique to this document then you may wish to change the "Save changes in" dropdown to your document name.

Comment: >"3. Click "Keyboard shortcuts: Customize" button.."

This doesn't exist in my dialog box..

Answer (score 3):

F5 is a standard shortcut to run a macro in VBA editor. I don't think you can add a shortcut key in editor itself. If you want to run the macro from excel, you can assign a shortcut from there.

In excel press alt+F8 to open macro dialog box. select the macro for which you want to assign shortcut key and click options. there you can assign a shortcut to the macro.

Answer (score 2):

F function keys (<kbd>F1</kbd>,<kbd>F2</kbd>,<kbd>F3</kbd>,<kbd>F4</kbd>,<kbd>F5</kbd> etc.) can be assigned to macros with the following codes :

```
Sub A_1()
    Call sndPlaySound32(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\a1.wav", 0)
End Sub

Sub B_1()
    Call sndPlaySound32(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\b1.wav", 0)
End Sub

Sub C_1()
    Call sndPlaySound32(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\c1.wav", 0)
End Sub

Sub D_1()
    Call sndPlaySound32(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\d1.wav", 0)
End Sub

Sub E_1()
    Call sndPlaySound32(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\e1.wav", 0)
End Sub


Sub auto_open()
    Application.OnKey "{F1}", "A_1"
    Application.OnKey "{F2}", "B_1"
    Application.OnKey "{F3}", "C_1"
    Application.OnKey "{F4}", "D_1"
    Application.OnKey "{F5}", "E_1"
End Sub
```

---

**In another template**, we used the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> keys to open the userform that we created to cut and move the selected row :

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Application.OnKey "^{F1}", "Show"
End Sub
Sub Show()
Cut_Row.Show
End Sub
```

[image]

[Source](https://eksi30.com/cut-rows-and-move-up-down-in-worksheet/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add some ALT+Letter shortcuts to the VBA editor environment.  I added ALT+C to Comment selected text lines and A+X to Uncomment selected text lines:

1. In the VBE, right-click on a toolbar and select Customize
2. Optionally create a new toolbar
3. Select the Command Tab and 'Edit' in the Categories listbox.  Find 'Comment Block' in the Commands listbox.  Click and drag it to the target toolbar.  Left-click on it to open the context popup menu and select 'Image and Text'.  Replace the name with &C.
4. Repeat step 3 for the Uncomment Block command and replace the name with &X.
5. Close the Customize popup window.

There are built-in Alt+Letter commands that cannot be used for new shortcuts using letters: A,D,E,D,H,I,O,Q,R,T,V,W.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself. The only solution I have is to record the macro in an excel workbook first. Then, drag and drop THE MODULE from the open workbook into the add-in modules. This will be a copy of the above module, but the keyboard shortcut you assigned to it will thankfully persist.

I just record a garbage macro and move it in there, then copy the code from my real module afterwords.

Felt so great to figure this out, I felt like I had to reply to the 5 year old posts I found on the subject!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I had with the above is that I wanted to associate a short cut key with a macro in an xlam which has no visible interface. I found that the folllowing worked

To associate a short cut key with a macro

In Excel (not VBA) on the Developer Tab
click Macros - no macros will be shown
Type the name of the Sub
The Options button should then be enabled
Click it
Ctrl will be the default
Hold down Shift and press the letter you want
eg Shift and A
will associate Ctrl-Shift-A with the Sub

Comment: (1) Use periods. If you are going to Capitalize "key" words like "Click" and "Ctrl", well ... read this part of  your text: "*Sub The Options button should then be enabled Click it Ctrl will be the default*". I.e., Capitalization does not indicate that previous sentence ended with an "implied period". (2) This doesn't answer original question.

Answer (score 0):

Write a vba proc like:

```
Sub E_1()
    Call sndPlaySound32(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\e1.wav", 0)
    Range("AG" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select 'go to column AG in the same row
End Sub
```

then go to developer tab, macros, select the macro, click options, then add a shortcut letter or button.