# Excel VBA: Macro hangs after opening a document when run via shortcut key, but runs perfectly from VB editor

Tags: vba, excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I ran into a strange problem, I decided to assign a keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + P` on one of my routine in VBA. This routine is suppose to open an existing excel workbook, copy some informations and `.SaveAs` another name.

This actually runs fine when I hit Play in the Visual Basic Editor. However, when I use the keyboard shortcut inside Excel to run my code, it stop working after opening the document.

I reproduce the problem in this sample:

```
Public Sub WriteData()
    Dim templatePath As String
    Dim templateWorkbook As Workbook

    'it seems to hang on the following line
    Set templateWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(templatePath)

    With templateWorkbook.Worksheets.Application
        .Range("B3") = "Employee name"
        .Range("B4") = "Employee first name"
        .Range("B5") = "Employee email"
    End With

    templateWorkbook.SaveAs(ThisWorkbook.Path & "Test")
    templateWorkbook.close
End Sub
```

I am using Excel 2007.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more easily find-able from a search engine. Hope you dont mind.

Comment: @SanthanSalai sure no worries! that's way better thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, after multiples google search about that particular problems, it seems that

```
Application.Workbooks.Open(yourPath)
```

mixed with the **Shift** keyboard key in your shortcut is the problem. More precisely [from this guy](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc9578cd-1b0c-4f00-a233-db5792e52316/macro-doesnt-run-via-shortcut-but-does-run-from-vb) if you look at the last answer:

> The shift key makes a vb script stop at any Open statement.

So you have two solutions

1. Remove the **Shift** key from your shortcut and choose another one
2. Instead of using `.Open`, you could use `.Add` which will do the same job, but the code won't hang. So if you do `Application.Workbooks.Add(yourPath)` it should behave properly.

*It is funny though, that both `Open` and `Add` have the exact same behavior when you look at the screen while running the Macro.*

**Edit:**
I couldn't find any official link referring to that bug.

Comment: Thanks - had the same problem today (using ctrl-shift-g to run a macro which opened another spreadsheet), and can confirm that changing Application.Workbooks.Open to Application.Workbooks.Add worked for me.

Comment: @GeoffS Glad to help at least one person :) Remember that on SO the way to express that a solution worked, or that a question was good, is to Upvote them :) Answering question is reserved to answers, commenting is usually to ask OP to add more info, or to say relevant info about a post. However, you cannot comment on user post before you reach 50 reputation point :)

Comment: I ran into the same problem today. +1 for adding alternate to .open. I'll be using .add from here on.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for sharing. Never would have put the blame on the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Noumenon Yeah, it blind sided me at the time! :)