# Copying cells from one workbook to another works on step through but not when run

Tags: vba, debugging, excel

I'm writing up a sub which grabs specific cells from the active workbook (order form), opens a specified workbook (report) and drops in the values in a particular order. Oddly, this works just fine when stepped through and I can see the report workbook open and the values fill, but when run it opens the workbook but doesn't seem to change it.

Code as follows (a bit rough and ready, I'm still learning...)

```
Sub TransferTheData()

Dim mySheet As Worksheet, myOtherSheet As Worksheet
Dim myOtherBook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim vToday As String

Set myOtherBook = Workbooks.Open("c:\\Test\Test Report.xlsx")
Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Order Form")
Set myOtherSheet = myOtherBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

vToday = Format(Date, "dd/mmmm/yyyy")

j = myOtherSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For i = 18 To 85
        If mySheet.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            'Loop through 68 rows and copy values
            myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 3).Value = mySheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
            myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 4).Value = mySheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
            myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 5).Value = mySheet.Cells(i, 3).Value
            'constant values copied to each row in report sheet
            myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value = mySheet.Cells(5, 2).Value
            myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 2).Value = mySheet.Cells(9, 5).Value
            myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 8).Value = vToday
            myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 6).Value = mySheet.Cells(9, 2).Value
            myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 7).Value = mySheet.Cells(6, 2).Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong? Been looking at it for hours scratching my head...

Comment: Almost forgot to mention. When I change it to copy to a different sheet inside the original workbook it runs ok. The problem seems to be related to the destination sheet being within a separate workbook?

Comment: Nothing looks strange there...  Worth adding `Debug.Print j` after getting the start row for copying: maybe it's way down on the sheet and you're not seeing the copied content because it's out of view?

Comment: No macros in "Test Report.xlsx"? How are you starting the macro?

Comment: The macro is run from within the order form (test order form.xlsm in this case, but the name could potentially be different each time).

Comment: Hmm... I've just discovered that it actually runs ok from the macro dialogue and ok when assigned to a button on the order form sheet. I've assigned it to shortcut key ctrl+shift+W and that's how I've been calling the procedure but that just opens the workbook and doesn't copy any data. What could be stopping the keyboard shortcut from working..?

Comment: Added an extra piece of code to check if the report workbook is open first and use the open book if so. Now the keyboard shortcut works fine if the book is open but if the workbook is closed it will open but won't copy data. It's got to be something to do with this line - Set myOtherBook = Workbooks.Open("c:\Test\Test Report.xlsx")

Comment: Have you tried putting `Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Order Form")` before opening the other workbook? I don't see why that'd be the problem, but you never know! Also, `Rows.Count` would be safer used like this `myOtherSheet.Rows.Count`.

Comment: Thanks @BernardSaucier no joy though. Same behaviour. I could just forego the keyboard shortcut, but I'm intrigued as to why it wouldn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Quite typically, after looking at it for hours and then posting a question, I found the answer right here on SO!

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409524/excel-vba-the-keyboard-shortcut-i-assigned-on-a-macro-make-my-code-hang-after-o) discusses and answers the issue. No shift keys in keyboard shortcuts using the Open method of the workbook object (I think):

> The shift key makes a vb script stop at any Open statement.

Switched .open for .add and we're rolling with full functionality as expected! :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out!!

Comment: .add didn't quite work out.It created a new iteration of the report workbook each time rather than seeing the open workbook. Just changed the shortcut to Shift+T and the original code worked o_O Thanks for your help!