# Context-menu and keyboard shortcut return different results on the same method

Tags: vba, excel, keyboard

I have a vba sub ("*sub*") in excel 2013, which opens another workbook, reads some data out of it, return this data and close the newopened workbook. It is possible to run this sub via **keyboard shortcut** and a entry in the **context menu**.

This call (the "UTILS.sub" this is) works perfectly fine:

```
' Add the sub-call to a new context menu entry
Call UTILS.addContextMenuEntry("Caption", 2556, "UTILS.sub")
```

But this call doesn't:

```
' Add the sub-call to a new keyboard shortcut
App.OnKey "+^{M}", "UTILS.sub"
```

If i call *sub* with the keyboard shortcut it breaks without an error. I've managed to work out the specific code line, at which it breakes via debugging:

```
'[...]

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Open the external Workbook
Set wbHandle = Workbooks.Open("wb.xls", ReadOnly:=True)
MsgBox "Debug"

'[...]
```

wb.xls opens (and displays), but the MsgBox "Debug" does not. Nothing after the "Open"-line does run and no breakpoint after this line will be hit. Another strange thing: If i debug a call of *sub* with a breakpoint before that line, it all works perfectly.

How to get the sub to run correctly, not regarding wether it was called by a context menu entry or keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Either don't include the Shift key in the shortcut, or test for it in the code that opens the workbook: http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/WorkbookOpenBug.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my problem by myself: [stackoverflow.com/questions/17409524/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409524/)

Apparently, excel can't handle the "Workbooks.Open()"-method if the sub is called through a keyboard shortcut, which includes the [SHIFT]-key. Solution: Use "Workbooks.Add()" instead.

Comment: Not strictly true - it will work fine as long as you don't use the Shift key in the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *exactly* sure what the cause of this behavior is, but I suspect that macros called via keyboard shortcuts or context menus are actually passed through `Application.Run` or something else that can reset the execution state internally.

The simple work-around seems to be to pass execution through a "wrapper" sub:

```
Public Sub bar()
    foo
End Sub

Public Sub foo()
    Dim bar As Workbook
    Set bar = Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xls", ReadOnly:=True)
    MsgBox "foo"
End Sub
```

Launching `foo` by a keyboard shortcut will not display the message box, but calling `bar` will.