# Excel Macro Called via Keyboard Shortcut Requires Stop in Code to Work

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Macro which works when called via manually hitting start and when calling via 'iRibbon' but not when called via "keyboard shortcut". I have debugged as far as I can to find the problem line of code, but I have no idea the fix or root cause. When I inject a "stop" in my code, then hit "play" after the stop, when calling the macro via "keyboard shortcut", it works. If I comment out the stop, the macro fails to continue on,  without error.

Any ideas?

Here is the macro:

```
Sub KBTest()
 Application.OnKey "+^{H}", "Testing"
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Test()
 Debug.Print "Here"
  
 Dim URL As String
 URL = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/4/E/14EDED28-6C58-4055-A65C-23B4DA81C4DE/Financial%20Sample.xlsx"
 Dim ActiveWB As Workbook, URLWB As Workbook
 Set ActiveWB = ActiveWorkbook
 'Stop 'With this stop, uncommented, I can run via KBShortcut
 Set URLWB = Workbooks.Open(URL, ReadOnly:=True)
 Debug.Print "WB Opened"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can reproduce with the public URL and keyboard shortcut. Adding `ReadOnly`, e.g. changing to `Set URLWB = Workbooks.Open(URL, ReadOnly:=True)`, continued.

Comment: @BigBen I still get the same problem when calling via Keyboard Shortcut, But I'll update my code w/ your improvements

Comment: @BigBen Got it! Looks like it was a dup, but hard to search obviously. Also, a MS Bug.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to switch `.Open` to `.Add`. This appears to be a bug. See this post for further details.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17409525/5079799