# VBA Debuging and Release different When Excel Open new Files

Tags: excel, vba

When I open this excel file in VBA code,

it is working well in debug mode. ( When I put debug point to "Set tmpWB = Workbooks.Open(filepath & fileName)")

But It is not working when I execute the vba code on Excel like release mode.

File is opened. But that's all. There is no data "iiii, jjjj, ooooo".

But I already told you, The code is working well when I attached debug point at "Set tmpWB = Workbooks...."

```
   Set tmpWB = Workbooks.Open(filePath & fileName)
   
   wk.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = "iiii"
   
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=filePath & "temp.xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8, CreateBackup:=False
        
   wk.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Value = "jjjj"
   
   tmpWB.Close
   
   wk.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(3, 1).Value = "ooooo"
```

Why does it work when debug mode, and not release mode?
How can I debug this?

Comment: Test it with more than one workbook open. Or is there a reason you are using `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: In order for us to give you an accurate solution **1.** Share the complete code. How are you declaring the objects and how are you initializing it.  **2.** Do not type the code. Copy and paste the exact code. Currently your code has a typo. Which means you typed it.

Comment: About 1. I couldn't attach complete code because my owner prohibit to open any full source code. About 2, I'm lazy. So I didn't type code. I attached code from source. Which means I didn't type it.. If there was miss, After I attached and occurred.

Comment: And There is no reason I am using ActiveWorkbook. Just I saw the code from other site for saving to other type(xlsx -> xls). If it might problem, I can change it.

Comment: As @braX 's advice, I tried to open other xlsx file. (Sincerely, I couldn't think about that.). Unfortunately, The problem occured again. It's like "Schrödinger's cat"

Comment: I tried to attach ```On Error GoTo Err_Check
   Set tmpWB = Workbooks.Open(filePath & fileName)
      
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=filePath & "tempcate.xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8, CreateBackup:=False
   
   tmpWB.Close``` ... ```Err_Check:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Err num : " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
        "Desc : " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    End If``` ... But It doesn't go here. But, It is stuck after running "ActiveWorkbook.open" on release mode.

Comment: Who debug, on menu, click in "View" "Immediate windows" use debug.print YOURVARIABLE to show valeu of that. or use ?variable on the immediate windows to show that is content value.

Comment: As @Julio Gadioli Soares advice, I tried to execute code in "immediate windows", And I found something. Saved file(temp.xls) is different. On debug mode, Saved file was newly opened file. But here, Saved file is initial open excel file. I didn't find the reason yet. I'm tring to find the reason now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Private Function WriteTOZerom()
On Error GoTo Err_Control
    Dim tmpWB As Workbook
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    
    FilePath = "C:\" 'remember to use \ at the end
    Filename = "YourFile.xlsm"
    Set tmpWB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & Filename)
       
       tmpWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "iiii"
       tmpWB.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = "jjjj"
       tmpWB.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 1).Value = "ooooo"
       tmpWB.Sheets(1).Range("A4").Value = "uuuuuu"
       '1(one) is the first sheet, if want use the name like you do, is work too.
        tmpWB.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath & "temp.xls", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        'tmpWB.Close SaveChanges:=True ' to save in same file this edition, or
        'tmpWB.Close SaveChanges:=false 'to close and not save in this same file edited.

Err_Control:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Err.Description: " & Err.Description & Chr(13) & _
        "Err.Number: " & Err.Number & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & _
        "if you want to make a paragraph: use chr(13) in between '&' "
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this code. And result is same. File opened, but it was stuck. there is no "iiii" in previous and next excel files.

Comment: use Application.DisplayAlerts = False before open and return to True after make your changes, like code above.

Comment: I already use it Because some excel files make alarm.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new workbook file

```
Private Function NewFileTOZerom()
    On Error GoTo Err_Control
        Dim FilePath As String
        Dim Filename As String
        Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        FilePath = "C:\YOUR PATH\" 'remember to use \ at the end
        Filename = "temp.xls"
            wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "1"
            wb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = "22"
            wb.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 1).Value = "333"
            wb.Sheets(1).Range("A4").Value = "4444"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            wb.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath & Filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            wb.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Err_Control:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Err.Description: " & Err.Description & Chr(13) & _
        "Err.Number: " & Err.Number
    End If
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my case I should to  open xlsx file and save it to xls for sheet copy. That's why I tried to open and save xlsx file.

Comment: FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook save on xls With the code that is already possible to do everything you need, join the functionalities of one with the other, in fact I didn't understand exactly what I wanted to do. Was there any doubt? anything else i can help?

Comment: Unfortunately, problem is not this. My situation is "VBA occured stuck at 'Set tmpWB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & Filename)'". When I set debugging point at this line, It is work well. But  It is not work when there is no debug breaker. So It can't run until `wb.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath & Filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

Comment: This is strange to happen, when we put points and interruption, it may happen that they are fixed without asking for this to happen, the tip I give is to use in Debug, the option Clear all the interruption points. and use On error Goto Err_Control create your error control, .. Err_Control: if err.number <> 0 then msgbox err.description endif, put a stop here to see what could be causing the error. and search for the errors, check if you are pointing to the file correctly, there is code to check if the file exists, if the folder exists, there is code for everything my friend. all the best there

Answer (score -1):

It looks some problem. "Macro In Excel Stops After A Workbook.Open Command"

I just thought it was debugger problem ;;..

So I changed "Workbook.open" to "GetObject".

Thanks for guys. specially @Julio Gadioli Soare

(It is mysterious why it is work or not whether there is debugger point or not)

Answer (score -1):

No. It was not problem. Problem was "When I execute This macro by shortcut with `Workbook.open`, It can be stuck". When I execute this macro on vba directly it is working. I think I have to check this. (Shift short key + open instruction can make stop...) Use `Application.Workbooks.Add` instead of `Workbook.open`. or doesn't use short key "shift". This was solution.

Thanks everyone. Specially @Julio Gadioli Soares

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409524/excel-vba-macro-hangs-after-opening-a-document-when-run-via-shortcut-key-but-r