# Assigining Keyboard Shortcut to Add-in

Tags: excel, vba, add-in, shortcut

I have created an add-in that is a Userform.

How can I do to assign a keyboard shortcut (to show the form) so I can use it when I load it in any Workbook ?

Thanks!

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14209798/2521004) for keyboard shortcut and then just call your form.

Comment: Thanks Portland! Even though I know how to assign a keyboard shortcut to a normal spreadsheet/workbook, I am no sure how to assign as an add-in. 
I don't know if it's possible.
I open an spreadsheet and then I load the add-in. Is it possible to assign a keyboard short without writing any commands in the new spreadsheet? I mean, just with the add-in itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application.OnKey` method works at the application level, not just the workbook or worksheet level. If you set OnKey, that code will run wherever you are.

I use `Sub Auto_Open()` to set the hotkeys when my addins load. This is the old style (the new style being an AddIn_Load event.

Make sure you set remove the shortcut in `Sub Auto_Close()` or a similar event procedure.