# Invoke a Sub when I press a key in vba powerpoint

Tags: vba, keyboard-shortcuts, powerpoint

This code captures the active window and paste it to power point slides by taking number screenshots to be pasted, by calling a `sub PrintScreen`, After that it takes 5 seconds to capture screen of active window. While i want that whenever i press a specific key like 'F7 or F3 etc' it should take print screen instead of waiting 5 seconds. I just want to press the key and it invokes sub in which i specify the print and paste and other functions.

```
Sub Screen_Capture_VBA()
 Dim Sec4 As Date
 MsgBox "Note: Three seconds after you click OK " & _
 "the active window will be copied to the clipboard."
 Sec4 = DateAdd("s", 4, Now)
 myValue = InputBox("Give me no of screen shots you want to capture")
 For I = 1 To myValue
 PrintScreen
 Next I
End Sub
```

This is my print screen sub.

```
Sub PrintScreen()

Sleep 5000
keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0
keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0
keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0

ActivePresentation.Slides.Add 1, ppLayoutBlank
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to lack of features powerpoint doesnot support onkey.
So try to write a code in **C++** and assign keys to it and shell execute your code, like in your case assign **F7** to **ALT+PrintScrn** i.e when you press F7 it should take screenshot of your current window.
Here is the code for shell execution

```
Sub PrintScreen()
Dim sFullPathToExecutable As String
sFullPathToExecutable = "C:\Users\abc.exe"
Shell sFullPathToExecutable
End Sub
```

Comment: How can we do so in Word? I have the same problem statement. I want to run a sub which will keep running unless stopped, which calls another sub on observing that print screen is pressed and take that capture in the word doc. Can you please suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 9):

PowerPoint doesn't support assigning keyboard shortcuts to macros [like in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818047/excel-vba-assign-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-procedure). You can purchase third-party apps like [OfficeOne Shortcut Manager](http://officeone.mvps.org/ppsctmgr/ppsctmgr.html) but a simpler workaround is to add your macro to the Quick Access Toolbar.

1. Click the QAT dropdown arrow (highlighted yellow below)
2. Click `More Commands`
3. In the dropdown `Choose commands from` select **Macros**
4. Click the **YourPresentationName!PrintScreen** macro
5. Click the `Add >>` button
6. Click `OK`

[image]

Then you can use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (or whatever number the QAT assigns) to execute **PrintScreen()**. Press the <kbd>alt</kbd> key once to see what number shortcut PowerPoint has assigned to your macro.

[image]

Comment: I want code something like this
any key like thekey is **Alt(Keybd_event VK_MENU, 0 , 0, 0)<--it  is pressed** 
If thekey is pressed then
 goto sub
else 
  donothing

or something like this 

If thekey= true Then
      goto sub
Else 
  donothing


I know we can do this in excel via OnKey method but i'm facing problem in powepoint.