# VBA MAC PowerPoint KeyEvent

Tags: vba, macos, powerpoint, user32

I've a working PowerPoint macro for Windows:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeystate Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer

If GetAsyncKeystate(VK_ENTER) < 0 Then msgbox "Enter pressed!"
```

When I run this on a Mac I get the error: "file not found user32"

Obviously this has to do with the fact that there are no Windows libraries on a mac?

How can I determine if the [enter] is pressed with MAC VBA for PowerPoint. Is there a equivalent? I've searched a lot, nothing found...

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523054/invoke-a-sub-when-i-press-a-key-in-vba-powerpoint (the answer with the most upvotes)

Comment: yes, tried it al!

Comment: Maybe explain why it didnt work for you? Mac computers cannot use WIN API calls.

Comment: There are some relevant pages in the Apple Communities site, like this one: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6068292

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on Ron's site: https://www.macexcel.com/examples/setupinfo/detectkeypress/