# Excel: Running Another Macro on KeyUp

Tags: vba, excel, event-handling, keypress

I am trying to make a user form and there is a macro to show this. I want this macro (which shows the user form) to run when I press (keyUp) a key lets say <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Capslock</kbd> keys only.

I found a post at the below for the same but it is showing error when i run it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14209798/1279872

Please see the attached image for the error message:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8thupki17ajqde7/Picture1.png?dl=0

The vba code i am using is (Both procedures are on the same sheet)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{CAPSLOCK}", "testing"
    MsgBox ("test2")
End Sub

Sub testing()
    MsgBox ("test1")
End Sub
```

The excel can be downloaded from the following link (if you want to see the same):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/c277skeywsrkbzy/Book1.xlsm?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ThisWorkbook` you need to put:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{CAPSLOCK}", "testing"
    MsgBox ("test2")
End Sub
```

The sub `testing` should be in a module.

Comment: it is not loading the form now, am a complete beginner with VBA


https://www.dropbox.com/s/c277skeywsrkbzy/Book1.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: change `Load UserForm1` to `UserForm1.Show`

Comment: Thanks its perfect now :)