# How to run code with a keystroke (not button)?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to increment the value of a cell by 1 when I input a specific key combination.

I used Record Macro but when I edit that code it doesn't show how it binds the macro to the keystroke.

Here's the code I have that does *not* work:

```
Sub IncTest2()
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
End Sub

Sub KeyTest()
    Application.OnKey "^a", "IncTest2"
End Sub
```

It should increment the active cell by 1 with "Control+a", but instead it does the standard "Control+a" keyboard shortcut.

Comment: look at the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818047/excel-vba-assign-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-procedure  it walks you through how to assign a keyboard short cut to an existing macro.

Comment: Since you have Sub IncTest2() and Excel VBA defaults procedures to public, you can click on Macros->View Macros, select the Macro and click Options there you will Bind the Macro to your key without writing any code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this and see if it works for you.  In the ThisWorkBook code, add the sub below.

```
Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "^a", "IncrementByeOne"
End Sub
```

In a module in ThisWorkBook, add the macro below.

```
Sub IncrementByeOne()

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: did you run the keytest on opening?