# Assign keyboard shortcut to macro inside the code

Tags: vba, excel, shortcut

I wrote a macro that change data in my excel, and I wrote other macro that 
insert the first macro (I made) inside 1000+ different excels that don't have this macro. In regular situation I know how to assign keyboard shortcut to this macro: via "option" in Macro windows.

but my goal is that the keyboard shortcut for Sub Single in Macro1 will remains also in all other excels, I think the best way is to do it in my code.
I read the following articles but cant figure out where they want me to put the following code, so it will actually work?

Thanks in advance for all helprs ..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461.aspx
and that one: 
[Excel VBA: Assign keyboard shortcut to run procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818047/excel-vba-assign-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-procedure)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.OnKey "^b", "Macro1"

End Sub
```

Comment: try putting the Application.Onkey statement in the sub Workbook_Open() of the workbook. That should do the trick.

Comment: @NiH not really working.. i tried inside "sheet1" and"thisWorkbook" as well 
can't make it work