# EXCEL VBA hide sheet and email issues

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am trying to email an Excel file having a sheet with controls hidden from the users.

Currently, on click of button it hides the sheet and emails the flie using VBA code.

However, there are 2 issues.
1) To unhide this sheet, I have to go to VBA code, to the immediate window, and type

For Each ws In Sheets:ws.Visible=True:Next

..and hit enter.

Is there a better way to do this since a senior manager would be executing and emailing report.

2) The file which is emailed, anyone can go to VBA code, and immediate window ...follow the steps and unhide the tab. how to make it permanently hidden in the file which is emailed without impacting the source file?

Here is code I am using to hide it:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet

Set sheet = ActiveSheet

' this hides the sheet so that it can only be made visible using VBA
sheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Admin").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyReport - " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsm"
```

'followed by code to email...

Answer (score 1):

Try making a new sub and have a button that the user can push to unhide all the sheets

```
Sub UnhideAllSheets()
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
   Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Great suggestions, Thanks! For the UnhideAllSheets on button click, problem I am thinking is that if I let it be visible, then any user can click it to unhide tabs who get that file, if I hide it then again the same issue of enabling tabs. Please suggest!

Comment: How about setting a keyboard shortcut for the macro instead of using a button?

Comment: @Robby, Sounds like a good idea. Please guide How would use a keyboard shortcut to fire a macro. thanks

Comment: @SilverFish check this link out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818047/excel-vba-assign-keyboard...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818047/excel-vba-assign-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-procedure)

Comment: @DaBeau96- Worked, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To unhide the sheet, you could create another macro to run the code that you're manually typing in.

To hide the VBA code, in the editor, you can go to Tools > VBAProject Properties > Protection, and then choose to lock it with or without a password.