# Error running macro

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

I'm having errors message running my macro with the codes below.

Error message when runned directly from Excel Workbook

> We didn't fill in the values because the display formatting for some of the cells in the active column is using a different level of precision underlying value

Error message when runned via VBA

> Run time error 9, Subscript out of range,

on code `With Windows("InstData_TEMS_Existing").Sheets("L")`

```
 Sub Graph()
'
' Graph Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'
'Select values in a column from specified workbook and sheet
Dim LR As Long, cell As Range, rng As Range

With Workbooks("Area3-LG").Sheets("Graph data")
LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In .Range("B4:B" & LR)
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = cell
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell
End With
rng.Copy ' copy the union range (no need to select it first)

'Paste without all the selecting
'Error code below
With Windows("InstData_TEMS_Existing").Sheets("L")
' Paste (without select) un the next empty cell fromn column AA
.Range("AA" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial     Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Go back to previous workbook & delete column
Workbooks("Area3-LG").Sheets("Graph data").Columns("B:B").Delete         Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the Sheet "L" exist in the activeworkbook?

Comment: Did you try With Workbooks("InstData_TEMS_Existing.xlsx").Sheets("L")?

Comment: `Windows("InstData_TEMS_Existing.xlsx")...`? or `.xlsm` or whatever it may be...or `Windows("InstData_TEMS_Existing.xlsx":1).Sheets(...`

Comment: @QHarr yup it exist.

Comment: @sktneer that actually solve my code. However I can only run from VBA mode, but running from Excel workbook gives me the same error as mentioned above

Comment: @BruceWayne Is able to run with sktneer code by VBA but unable to run directly from Excel workbook showing the same message

Comment: @Tyler If you try to run it with Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+E then this won't work because this shortcut is already used by a built-in Excel function called [Flash Fill](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-AutoFill-and-Flash-Fill-2e79a709-c814-4b27-8bc2-c4dc84d49464). This function causes the error not your macro! Define a [new shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14161230/3219613) which is not already used by Excel and it will work: [List of shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-keyboard-shortcuts-and-function-keys-for-Windows-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f).

Comment: @Peh That solves it. Hehe thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have changed your code as *sktneer* suggested (using `With Workbooks("InstData_TEMS_Existing.xlsx").Sheets("L")` rather than `With Windows(...`) and you get an subscript out of bounds error, it can be either that the file `InstData_TEMS_Existing.xlsx` is not open or that it doesn't have a sheet `L` in it. I would suggest to put 2 Debug.Print statements above the `with`-statement.

```
Debug.print Workbooks("InstData_TEMS_Existing.xlsx").name
Debug.print Workbooks("InstData_TEMS_Existing.xlsx").sheets("L").name
```

Then set a breakpoint to the beginning of the code (`F9`) and step thru the code (`F8`). Tf your range is large, maybe set another breakpoint on the `rng.Copy` statement and let it run (`F5`). Watch where exactly the runtime error happens.