# How do I add a keyboard shortcut key to a module of VBA already coded free hand?

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard-shortcuts

Here are the first few lines of code:

```
Sub OpenFile()

     Dim myFile As String
     Dim Wb As Workbook

     myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv")
     'Exit if no file selected

     If myFile = "False" Then
          MsgBox "No file selected!"
          Exit Sub
     End If
     'Open the file

End Sub
```

I have tried mimicking the command lines found in other macros I had recorded but nothing seems to work.  Please advise.  And where exactly do I put the line of code specifying a keyboard shortcut key?  In this instance, I want the shortcut key to be CTRL+SHIFT+R

Thank you!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14161230/1164465

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign keyboard shortcut to run procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818047/assign-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

From the worksheet, touch <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>
Then touch <kbd>Options...</kbd>
Then assign the shortcut.

[image]