# How to automate the execution of this macro?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub HURows()
    Dim BeginRows() As Variant
    Dim EndRows() As Variant
    ChkCol = 6

    BeginRows = Array(12, 20, 26, 36, 43, 51, 60, 72, 79)
    EndRows = Array(15, 21, 31, 38, 46, 55, 67, 74, 81)

    For Index = 0 To UBound(BeginRows)
        For RowCnt = BeginRows(Index) To EndRows(Index)
            If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 0 Then
                Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next RowCnt
    Next Index
End Sub
```

I have this macro below, but I need it to be automatically performed instead of having to go to Developer tab and pressing "Run". Is there any way to do it, like adding a line of instruction to the below existing macro?

Comment: Please choose tags that are relevant to the **subject matter** of your question.  This looks like some dialect of Basic  (probably VBA).  It is nothing to do with either Openstack or stack overflows.  Posting a question with obscure irrelevant tags is only a good idea if you *want* people to ignore it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign keyboard shortcut to run procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9818047/11683)

Comment: How would you like to automatically perform this? By time or by some event?

Comment: Hi, for example, if I change some selections on the tab in front, this tab automatically gets updated. For example, in my first tab, I have Item A 300 units, Item B 400 units and Item C 500 units. If I change Item B to zero units, its line in the 2nd tab will automatically hide itself since it is zero value. If I change back to Item B 400 units in the 1st tab, its line on Tab B will automatically unhide itself since there is value now

Answer (score 0):

Make the first sheet the active one and press Alt+F11 to open the respective sheet code spot...

Once you open place this code on it

```
'This is the event that will trigger when some cell is changed on the sheet
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 Then ' If the target column is the second one
        Select Case Target.Row
            Case 12 To 15, 20 To 21, 26 To 31, 36 To 38, 43 To 46, 51 To 55, 60 To 67, 72 To 74, 79 To 81
            'If target row that is being change is the ones referenced on the case
                Dim targetSheet As Worksheet ' We need to reference the target sheet you desire
                Set targetSheet = Worksheets("Folha2") 'Change the Sheet2 to the name of your target sheet
                If Trim(Target.Value) = 0 Then ' If the value of the cell is 0
                    targetSheet.Cells(Target.Row, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True ' Set the target sheet row to hidden
                    MsgBox "hidden"
                ElseIf Trim(Target.Value) > 0 Then 'If the value is superior to 0
                    targetSheet.Cells(Target.Row, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False ' Set the target sheet row to not hidden
                    MsgBox "un-hidden"
                End If ' Close the second if statement
        End Select
    End If ' Close the firts if statement
End Sub ' Close the sub routine
```

Please keep in mind to change the **Sheet2** tab name to your sheet name.

Comment: Code was updated duo to an error on the event name (was using before SelectionChange instead of Change and it seems you wanted only some rows to trigger the hidden/unhidden thing

Comment: Thank you for your code, however it does not work. Would you be able to advise what can be include into below code, so the Marco will automatically be performed instead of having to go to Developer tab and pressing "Run.

Comment: Sub HURows()
    Dim BeginRows() As Variant
    Dim EndRows() As Variant
    ChkCol = 6

    BeginRows = Array(12, 20, 26, 36, 43, 51, 60, 72, 79)
    EndRows = Array(15, 21, 31, 38, 46, 55, 67, 74, 81)

    For Index = 0 To UBound(BeginRows)
        For RowCnt = BeginRows(Index) To EndRows(Index)
            If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 0 Then
                Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next RowCnt
    Next Index
End Sub

Comment: you cannot include nothing on that code to run automatically... You will always have to use some kind of event code (trigger) to run it automatically and in this case if the Change event...

Comment: Once you press Alt+F11 (like i said on the topic) it will popup the Microsoft Visual Basic Editor with a small windows on the left side that say's "Project - VBAProject"... Inside that window you will a "Microsoft Excel Object" treeview. Double click on the first tab sheet name. When you double-click it will popup a window on the right side, place the code on it.