# VBA Application.Calculate with F9

Tags: excel, vba

we have to decline all Excel4 Makros regarding the Update of MS.

I want to provide a circle in Excel which mean that I want to calculate with "F9", 'Following Code and calculate new. I don't know how to reach out "F9" + Code

```
Sub ReCalculation()
   Application.Calculate     '1st Calculation
   MsgBox "Test"             'Following Code
   Application.Calculate     'Re-Calculation of the full Sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to bind the F9 key to a macro? If so, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14209798/4742570) to a similar question.

Comment: I cannot get you, I am afraid... `Application.Calculate` calculates all open workbooks, `Worksheets(1).Calculate` calculates only first worksheet, `Worksheets(1).rows(1)` calculates only the first row of the first sheet and `Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("B:C").Calculate` calculates columns B:C in the used range of the first sheet...

Comment: @jsheeran Yes that's correct. Thank I've seen it but it doesn't work. I will continue to try

Comment: @FaneDuru I want a macro to copy an area directly after the calculation and use it again with values. Then it should be recalculated (automatically). That all to prevent a circle

Comment: Then, use `Calculate` for the respective range, as I suggested above...